# Android layout: How to put 2 TextViews next to each other with minimum space

Tags: android, android-layout, width

How can I put 2 TextViews with dynamic text besides each other so that the width of the TextViews automatically changes to minimize the height of both TextViews? 
So the TextView with the larger text should be broader and the height of both TextViews (amount of lines) should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

here use this code.
The height of both the textview will be the same and the width of the textview with more text will take more space

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this does not seem to work in every case. When I use it and the user has his settings set to large fonts, sometimes the left TextView needs only 1 line while the right one needs 3 lines, even though it would be possible to break the text to use only 2 lines in both TextViews. Even when I set android:maxLines="2" it rather leaves the 3rd line out then to break it correctly. Seems to be a bug in the implementation.